# Eigenvalues in $L^2(\Omega\times\Omega)$ equivalent to the pairwise sum of eigenvalues in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $H_x$ and $H_y$ are Hermitian operators defined on $L^2([0,1])$. Their eigenfunctions and eigenvalues are $\{f_i(x),a_i\}$ and $\{g_j(y),b_j\}$, respectively. Now if we work in the space $L^2([0,1]\times [0,1])$, will the system $\{f_i(x)g_j(y),a_i+b_j\}$ be equivalent to the eigensystem of the operator $H_x+H_y$?

Comment: The eigenvalues of $L_x\oplus L_y$ are $\{\lambda_x^i\}\cup\{\lambda_y^i\}$. The eigenvectors are also the disjoint union, not the product which in this context makes no sense. Note that only if $L_x,L_y$ are self-adjoint that the eigenvectors are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: @s.harp. Assume $L$ are Hermitian. Do we have $(L_x+L_y)f_i(x)g_i(y)=g_i(y)L_xf_i(x)+f_i(x)L_yg_i(y)=g_i(y)\lambda_x^if_i(x)+f_i(x)\lambda_y^ig_i(y)=(\lambda_x^i+\lambda_y^i)f_i(x)g_i(y)$

Comment: Maybe my question is a bit incorrect. $L_x$ and $L_y$ are both defined in the product space $X\times Y$, but $L_x$ only operates with regard to elements in $X$, i.e. $L_x g(y)=0$ for any $g(y)$, likewise for $L_y$. They are like the linear second-order differential operators. Because eigenfunctions and eigenvalues are easy to obtain for $L_x$ alone operating on elements in the subspace $X$, I was trying to obtain in this way the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the sum of the two operators in the whole space.

Comment: Sorry I think the original question is wrong because I shouldn't use the product space! See the modified version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I misunderstood your goal until you added some context.  I've kept the tensor product comment, but I've added the operator you originally intended.

The eigensystem $\{f_i(x)g_j(y), a_i b_j\}_{i, j}$ (note the product of eigenvalues) naturally corresponds to the tensor product operator $H_x \otimes H_y$ on $L^2([0,1]) \otimes L^2([0,1]) \simeq L^2([0,1] \times [0,1])$.  See the third section [here](http://users.ices.utexas.edu/~alen/articles/tensor.pdf).

Ignoring the issue of unboundedness, if you want to move an operator like $H_x = \partial_x$ from $L^2([0,1])$ to the product space $L^2([0,1]\times [0,1])$ in the natural way (so that $\delta_x (f(x)g(y)) = f'(x)g(y)$), then the corresponding operator is technically $H_x \otimes 1$.  So I think that by "$H_x + H_y$," you really mean $L = H_x \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes H_y$, which has the spectrum you found in the comments.  Since $(H_x \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes H_y)(f_i(x)g_j(y)) = a_i(f_i \otimes g_j) + b_j(f_i \otimes g_j) = (a_i+b_j)(f_i \otimes g_j)$, we get that the associated eigensystem is $\{f_i(x)g_j(y), a_i + b_j\}$, like you said.

Comment: In terms of the well-definedness of $L_x(g(y))=0$, it poses some constraint on the class of $L_x$. For instance, if $L_x(u)=\partial_x^2(h(x)\cdot u)$, then $L_x(1)$ might not be zero, so the problem is not well-behaved. But if $L_x = h(x) \partial^2_x(u)$, then the above situation is satisfied.

Comment: A specific example from the question I have been working on is this Fokker-Planck Operator $L$: $h_1(x)\partial^2_x+h_2(x)\partial_x+h_3(y)\partial^2_y+h_4(y)\partial_y$. If we split $L$  into the "x-part" and the "y-part", their eigenfunctions and eigenvalues are easy to solve in the corresponding space. From a probabilistic point of view, the "x" part and "y" part describe two independent stochastic differential equations evolving according to their own law, and the mathematical expectation $\mathbb{E} x^\alpha y^\beta$ should be decomposable to $\mathbb{E}x^\alpha \mathbb{E} y^\beta$

Comment: But the sum of the two split operators into $L$ does not look like a tensor product

Comment: I hadn't realized what situation you were going for there.  I've added the eigensystem for the operator I think you care about.

Comment: Thank you @Josh for the clarification!